# Java TCP Socket Connection Issue -- handshake failure while connecting to legacy equipment

Tags: java

I am attempting to write a Java program that will replace an old DOS-based program that my company currently uses. When I attempt to simply open a socket to communicate with the piece of equipment the program is being written for, the TCP handshake never completes. I have a fairly decent idea of what the problem may be, but I am truly a novice network programmer and I'm not totally sure (nor am I sure how to resolve the issue). I'll try to make this explanation both brief and useful.

The equipment that I'm attempting to connect with is OLD -- like 20+ years old. The device is typically controlled by either a GPIB connection or over a network. Historically, all the programs that have connected to this device over a network have been run on Solaris system. The GPIB port has been the only option available for PC-based connections.

Now, one downside is that I don't have access to any of the source code from either the "client" accessing the machine nor the "server" on the machine. All the information I have has been gleaned by intercepting the IP traffic between a Solaris box and the equipment. I do believe that the equipment is utilizing a UNIX-like embedded system. And if you want proof of how old these things are, check out the MAC address below that starts with "00:80:12:00".

The bottom line of my problem is this -- it seems that there is enough difference between the packets that my system and JVM (Win7 with Java 7) send and the packets that the equipment produce to cause a TCP connection to not function. I have a feeling that Java doesn't have any built-in methods or classes to functionally modify a TCP packet. I ran into a similar limitation when I was writing a RARP server and found out that I couldn't easily send a ping from a Java program.

I'm including some basic packet information that I've intercepted off the network. The first set of six packets are the first packets exchanged between the Solaris system and the equipment. The second set of six packets are the only six packets sent between my Windows 7-based Java program and the equipment. Key items that I've noticed already about the difference between these two sets of packets:

1) The port being used by this equipment is 2112 (AKA idonix-metanet). The extremely limited information I've found about this port/protocol just shows how utterly old this equipment and protocol are.
2) The working packets from the Solaris system do not contain any entry involving "WS=XXX". I'd imagine this is because that particular aspect of TCP didn't exist way-back-when.
3) It seems to me that my PC/program is the entity deciding to close the attempted TCP connection. When I open the socket in Java, it sends a SYN packet, receives a SYN, ACK packet, sends an ACK packet, then instantly sends a FIN, ACK packet which then starts the process of terminating the connection. To me and my limited experience, this tells me that something in the single SYN,ACK packet that was sent from the equipment made my program(or OS) decide that this connection was not working properly.
4) I also noticed that the value for "Win" was drastically different between the two. In the functional Solaris packets, Win starts off with a value of 24820. This value changes in later packets. I did manually modify my program to have a fixed Win value of 24820, but this had no effect.
5) The length of the first packet is four greater (66) in my Java-based communications than it is in the Solaris-based communications. This is probably due to the additional WS field.

I am not including any Java code since all I am doing at this point is opening a Socket to the equipment's IP and port.

First -- the working Solaris packets:

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      1 0.000000    192.168.1.135         192.168.1.23          TCP      62     33384 > idonix-metanet [SYN] Seq=0 Win=24820 Len=0 SACK_PERM=1 MSS=1460

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 00 03 ba 13 6b ec 08 00 45 00    .....3....k...E.
    0010  00 30 48 37 40 00 40 06 6e a2 c0 a8 01 87 c0 a8   .0H7@.@.n.......
    0020  01 17 82 68 08 40 cf f8 45 a0 00 00 00 00 70 02   ...h.@..E.....p.
    0030  60 f4 fd fa 00 00 01 01 04 02 02 04 05 b4         `.............
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      2 0.000970    192.168.1.23          192.168.1.135         TCP      60     idonix-metanet > 33384 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4096 Len=0 MSS=1024

```
    0000  00 03 ba 13 6b ec 00 80 12 00 03 33 08 00 45 00   ....k......3..E.
    0010  00 2c 00 05 00 00 64 06 d2 d8 c0 a8 01 17 c0 a8   .,....d.........
    0020  01 87 08 40 82 68 00 39 c0 00 cf f8 45 a1 60 12   ...@.h.9....E.`.
    0030  10 00 a5 5f 00 00 02 04 04 00 00 00               ..._........
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.000975    192.168.1.135         192.168.1.23          TCP      60     33384 > idonix-metanet [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=25600 Len=0

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 00 03 ba 13 6b ec 08 00 45 00   .....3....k...E.
    0010  00 28 48 38 40 00 40 06 6e a9 c0 a8 01 87 c0 a8   .(H8@.@.n.......
    0020  01 17 82 68 08 40 cf f8 45 a1 00 39 c0 01 50 10   ...h.@..E..9..P.
    0030  64 00 67 68 00 00 55 55 55 55 55 55               d.gh..UUUUUU
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.001235    192.168.1.135         192.168.1.23          TCP      62     33384 > idonix-metanet [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=25600 Len=8

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 00 03 ba 13 6b ec 08 00 45 00   .....3....k...E.
    0010  00 30 48 39 40 00 40 06 6e a0 c0 a8 01 87 c0 a8   .0H9@.@.n.......
    0020  01 17 82 68 08 40 cf f8 45 a1 00 39 c0 01 50 18   ...h.@..E..9..P.
    0030  64 00 26 55 00 00 41 03 00 00 00 00 00 00         d.&U..A.......
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 0.002694    192.168.1.23          192.168.1.135         TCP      60     idonix-metanet > 33384 [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=9 Win=4088 Len=0

```
    0000  00 03 ba 13 6b ec 00 80 12 00 03 33 08 00 45 00   ....k......3..E.
    0010  00 28 00 06 00 00 64 06 d2 db c0 a8 01 17 c0 a8   .(....d.........
    0020  01 87 08 40 82 68 00 39 c0 01 cf f8 45 a9 50 10   ...@.h.9....E.P.
    0030  0f f8 bb 68 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               ...h........
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 0.019280    192.168.1.23          192.168.1.135         TCP      62     idonix-metanet > 33384 [PSH, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=9 Win=4096 Len=8

```
    0000  00 03 ba 13 6b ec 00 80 12 00 03 33 08 00 45 00   ....k......3..E.
    0010  00 30 00 07 00 00 64 06 d2 d2 c0 a8 01 17 c0 a8   .0....d.........
    0020  01 87 08 40 82 68 00 39 c0 01 cf f8 45 a9 50 18   ...@.h.9....E.P.
    0030  10 00 79 fb 00 00 41 03 00 00 00 00 00 52         ..y...A......R
```

```
<br><br>
```

Now, the non-functional Java-based packets (packets 1 and 2 were removed since they were just broadcasts looking for the equipment's MAC address):

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      3 0.001154    192.168.1.79          192.168.1.23          TCP      66     49931 > idonix-metanet [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 14 da e9 1a c9 c4 08 00 45 00   .....3........E.
    0010  00 34 01 9a 40 00 80 06 75 73 c0 a8 01 4f c0 a8   .4..@...us...O..
    0020  01 17 c3 0b 08 40 22 6f b1 8d 00 00 00 00 80 02   .....@"o........
    0030  20 00 2c 11 00 00 02 04 05 b4 01 03 03 08 01 01    .,.............
    0040  04 02                                             ..
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      4 0.002375    192.168.1.23          192.168.1.79          TCP      60     idonix-metanet > 49931 [SYN, ACK] Seq=0 Ack=1 Win=4096 Len=0 MSS=1024

```
    0000  14 da e9 1a c9 c4 00 80 12 00 03 33 08 00 45 00   ...........3..E.
    0010  00 2c 00 05 00 00 64 06 d3 10 c0 a8 01 17 c0 a8   .,....d.........
    0020  01 4f 08 40 c3 0b 00 3a 70 00 22 6f b1 8e 60 12   .O.@...:p."o..`.
    0030  10 00 f6 8f 00 00 02 04 04 00 00 00               ............
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      5 0.002379    192.168.1.79          192.168.1.23          TCP      60     49931 > idonix-metanet [ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 14 da e9 1a c9 c4 08 00 45 00   .....3........E.
    0010  00 28 01 9b 40 00 80 06 75 7e c0 a8 01 4f c0 a8   .(..@...u~...O..
    0020  01 17 c3 0b 08 40 22 6f b1 8e 00 3a 70 01 50 10   .....@"o...:p.P.
    0030  fc 00 20 98 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               .. .........
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      6 0.003002    192.168.1.79          192.168.1.23          TCP      60     49931 > idonix-metanet [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=1 Win=64512 Len=0

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 14 da e9 1a c9 c4 08 00 45 00   .....3........E.
    0010  00 28 01 9c 40 00 80 06 75 7d c0 a8 01 4f c0 a8   .(..@...u}...O..
    0020  01 17 c3 0b 08 40 22 6f b1 8e 00 3a 70 01 50 11   .....@"o...:p.P.
    0030  fc 00 20 97 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               .. .........
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      7 0.004242    192.168.1.23          192.168.1.79          TCP      60     idonix-metanet > 49931 [FIN, ACK] Seq=1 Ack=2 Win=4096 Len=0

```
    0000  14 da e9 1a c9 c4 00 80 12 00 03 33 08 00 45 00   ...........3..E.
    0010  00 28 00 06 00 00 64 06 d3 13 c0 a8 01 17 c0 a8   .(....d.........
    0020  01 4f 08 40 c3 0b 00 3a 70 01 22 6f b1 8f 50 11   .O.@...:p."o..P.
    0030  10 00 0c 97 00 00 02 04 04 00 00 00               ............
```

No.     Time        Source                Destination           Protocol Length Info
      8 0.004246    192.168.1.79          192.168.1.23          TCP      60     49931 > idonix-metanet [ACK] Seq=2 Ack=2 Win=64512 Len=0

```
    0000  00 80 12 00 03 33 14 da e9 1a c9 c4 08 00 45 00   .....3........E.
    0010  00 28 01 9d 40 00 80 06 75 7c c0 a8 01 4f c0 a8   .(..@...u|...O..
    0020  01 17 c3 0b 08 40 22 6f b1 8f 00 3a 70 02 50 10   .....@"o...:p.P.
    0030  fc 00 20 96 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00               .. .........
```

So, now to my main question -- how in the world do I make this connection function properly in Java? My GUESS is that I'll need some C/C++ code to act as an intermediary between my program and my OS/hardware, but I really hope there is another way. I don't have the slightest clue how to do that.

Also, I do have all the Solaris-based header and compiled class files (C/C++) that are needed to access this equipment, but I don't know how useful compiled classes would be.

Many many thanks in advance for any help. Please let me know if there is any additional information that would help.

Jonathan

Comment: you said 'enough difference between the packets that my system and JVM (Win7 with Java 7) send and ...', have you tried establishing the connection from a C/C++/PERL etc program instead of Java, if C/C++ worked you could use JNI - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface

Comment: However C++ *won't* work any differently from Java. Java doesn't send SYN or ACK or FIN packets, the underlying TCP stack does that.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not including any Java code since all I am doing at this point is
>   opening a Socket to the equipment's IP and port.

Are you sure about that? Sure you're not closing the socket, or letting it be GC'd, or closing its input stream or output stream, or calling shutdownOutput()? Because those are the only things that will cause your host to send a FIN.

Comment: Wow -- you're totally right. I've been barking up the wrong tree. The TCP handshake is just fine. It just closes the connection immediately afterwards. Now on to the problem that made me think that I had a TCP issue... my program just sits waiting forever when I do a (Scanner object).hasNext(). Shouldn't it just return false if there is no input stream data?

Comment: @EJP Ha, wow. Good catch I was assuming something was incorrect in the handshake also.

Comment: @Jonathan Scanner can block on next/hasNext. The Scanner is for doing lexing of tokens. Until you get to EOF it won't stop. And it won't be EOF on your stream until you close the connection.

Comment: btw, +1 for finding such an obvious answer to the original problem. Sometimes we engineers look for problems where there are not any.

Comment: Well, the original problem still kind of exists, and I still do suspect that there is a pretty large difference in the way that Java on Windows 7 creates TCP packets and how my old Sparc Solaris Ultra 10 box does. I'm able to mimic two packet exchanges with Java in Windows 7 that I observed occurring between the Solaris box and the equipment, but then it all just breaks down. The third command I issue doesn't elicit a response like the first two.

Comment: @Jonathan Java doesn't create TCP packets at all. It just calls socket(), bind(), connect(), send(), recv(), etc. The kernel provides the TCP implementation. You are definitely barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: What about Jpcap? From what I've seen, it permits me to make some fairly fundamental changes to a packets form.

Comment: @Jonathon Jpcap lets you make up your own packets and send them via raw sockets. It doesn't let you alter packets already in flight.